# Creación de un servidor de PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, servidor

He comprado un VPS con Windows Server 2012 R2, aquí tendré las bases de datos en PostgreSQL pero quiero administrarla de manera remota desde mi Notebook a través de PG4.

Inserto todas las opciones, la dirección host (IP de mi servidor) establezco el puerto que lo deje por defecto 5432, el usuario, la constraseña, la base de datos y el nombre del servidor. Pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes me aparecía que el tiempo había expirado porque no tenia las reglas en el Firewall para permitir las conexiones en el puerto 5432. Es decir, abrí los puertos mediante las reglas de seguridad de mi servidor y estoy aceptando las peticiones. Una vez hice eso, el mensaje desapareció pero me aparece el de la imagen de arriba. No me da ningún error especifico solo ese mensaje.

Al hacer un ping a mi servidor con cmd no tengo problemas y obtengo respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé que más hacer, he reinstalado dos veces pero sigo con los mismos problemas. Estoy intentando instalar Linux en mi servidor pero no quiero hacerlo aún, espero que quizás alguien tuvo este problema.

Comment: puede intentar, a) Asegurece que el servicio de postgressql este arriba b) Colocar un nombre al servidor o host, c) registrar la ip 127.0.0.1 y la ip del servidor al nombre servidor en el archivo host, d) no conectar con localhost, intente con ip o con el nombre del servidor. Por otro PGADMIN4 es web por lo que el puerto de acceso a pgadmin4 es diferente al de la base de datos (5432),

Comment: Algo así era el problema, ya dí con la solución.

Comment: Puede compartir su solución, para que alguien más pueda orientarse en el futuro.

Comment: Lo haré, pero tengo que esperar dos días para marcar mi respuesta como la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que postgreSQL no viene iniciado para aceptar conexiones remotas, así para permitir el acceso se deben realizar los siguientes pasos.

1. Permitir las conexiones en el puerto establecido

Cuando se instala postgreSQL se debe especificar un puerto, por defecto el puerto es 5432. En Windows basta con ir al Firewall y agregar una nueva regla de entrada y de salida para el puerto 5432 y permitir las conexiones.

2. Editar el archivo postgresql.conf

En algunas instalaciones este archivo viene por defecto de la siguiente manera:

```
#listen_addresses = localhost
```

Debemos dejarlo así:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Además debemos quitar el signo gato de la siguiente línea:

```
password_encryption = on
```

El punto anterior es para encriptar las contraseñas de las conexiones.

3. Modificar las listas de acceso en el archivo pg_hba.conf

Agregar la siguiente línea al final del archivo.

```
host all all 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 md5
```

Luego debemos reiniciar el servicio, en Windows>services>postgresql - Reiniciar.

Y listo, luego podremos conectarnos desde otro computador mediante algun programa de administración, en mi caso PG4.

Los archivos a editar se encuentran en la carpeta data que asignaron en la instalación.